# How do I convert this PL/SQL update statement so that is works in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, plsql, translation

I've been asked to convert this statement from PL/SQL to SQL Server:

```
UPDATE pdi_nb_process_complete pdi_end1
SET    (pdi_end1.adp_issue_date_time, pdi_end1.adp_print_date_time) = 
(SELECT DISTINCT pdi_end1.completion_date + 2
                ,pdi_end1.completion_date
 FROM   cl100 cl
 WHERE  cl.polref = pdi_end1.policy_reference
 AND    cl.doctyp = 'PSP')
WHERE  pdi_end1.adp_print_date_time IS NULL
```

A straight copy/paste doesn't work - you get a compile error. The closest I have managed is this:

```
UPDATE pdi_end1
SET    pdi_end1.adp_issue_date_time = pdi_end1.completion_date + 2,
       pdi_end1.adp_print_date_time = pdi_end1.completion_date
from pdi_nb_process pdi_end1
INNER JOIN cl100 cl ON  cl.polref = pdi_end1.policy_reference
     AND cl.doctyp = 'PSP'
WHERE  pdi_end1.adp_print_date_time IS NULL
```

But this leaves me short of the **DISTINCT**. Does anyone have any suggestions?

You can assume the Oracle and SQL Server Databases have the same tables and fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move the *AND cl.doctyp='PSP'* condition to the WHERE, because it is not a join condition.

try this:

```
UPDATE pdi_end1
    SET pdi_end1.adp_issue_date_time=pdi_end1.completion_date + 2
        ,pdi_end1.adp_print_date_time)=pdi_end1.completion_date
    FROM pdi_nb_process_complete pdi_endl
        INNER JOIN cl100               cl ON cl.polref=pdi_end1.policy_reference
    WHERE pdi_end1.adp_print_date_time IS NULL
        AND cl.doctyp='PSP'
```

I would not worry about the DISTINCT, SQL Server will only update the rows one time, see this example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Test table (RowID int, RowValue int, OtherRowValue int)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 1, 1, 10)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 2, 2, 20)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 3, 3, 30)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 4, 4, 40)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 5, 5, 50)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 6, 6, 60)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 7, 7, 70)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 8, 8, 80)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ( 9, 9, 90)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (10,10,100)

DECLARE @TestJoin table (RowID int, RowValue int)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (1,10)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (1,10)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (1,10)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (2,20)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (2,20)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (2,20)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (2,20)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (2,20)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (3,30)
INSERT INTO @TestJoin VALUES (3,30)
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT ---------------------------returns 5 rows, DISTINCT would only return 1
    t.OtherRowValue+2
    FROM @Test                t
        INNER JOIN @TestJoin  j ON t.RowID=j.RowID
    WHERE t.OtherRowValue=20
        AND j.RowValue=20

UPDATE t--------------------------updates only 1 row
    SET t.RowValue=t.OtherRowValue+2
    FROM @Test                t
        INNER JOIN @TestJoin  j ON t.RowID=j.RowID
    WHERE t.OtherRowValue=20
        AND j.RowValue=20
```

OUTPUT:

```
-----------
22
22
22
22
22

(5 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The SELECT returns 5 rows, however when that same select is put into the UPDATE, only 1 row is affected.

Comment: "I would move the AND cl.doctyp='PSP' condition to the WHERE, because it is not a join condition." - Is this because it more efficient, or is it just personal preference?

Comment: in this case, personal preference, but it can makes difference in what rows are actually returned. Using my example code above, run this query: **SELECT t.*,j.RowValue FROM @Test t LEFT OUTER JOIN @TestJoin j ON t.RowID=j.RowID AND j.RowValue=20** and then run it moving the **j.RowValue=20** into a WHERE clause, you will get a different result set

Answer (score 0):

You could change the inner join into a subquery:

```
inner join (
    select distinct policy_reference
    from cl100
    where doctyp = 'PSP'
) cl on cl.polref = pdi_end1.policy_reference
```

Or maybe more readable, remove the inner join altogether and replace it with a WHERE statement:

```
WHERE  pdi_end1.adp_print_date_time IS NULL
AND EXISTS (
    select * 
    from cl100 cl
    where cl.polref = pdi_end1.policy_reference
    and cl.doctyp = 'PSP'
)
```